# How would you add a time offset using the same name as the class name for the parameter

Tags: java, time

I need to fill out the method for the time offset but using the class name as a parameter name and I don't know how to do it
I have tried adding the variables together but I get errors saying "You can't convert Time to an int"

So I have no clue on what to do,
please respond soon
thank you!

Error type:

```
Time.java:48: error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
       this.minutes += offset;
                    ^
  first type:  int
  second type: Time
1 error
```

```
public class Time
{
   // The values of the three parts of the time
   private int hours;
   private int minutes;
   private int seconds;

   public Time()
   {
      this.hours = 0;
      this.minutes = 0;
      this.seconds = 0;
   }

   public Time(int h, int m, int s)
   {
      this.hours = h;
      this.minutes = m;
      this.seconds = s;
   }
   
   public void add(Time offset)
   {
        // Part b: complete the add method
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return pad(hours) + ":" + pad(minutes) + ":" + pad(seconds);
   }

   private String pad(int value)
   {
      String sign = "";
      if (value < 0)
      {
         sign = "-";
         value = -1 * value;
       }
       if (value < 10) {
          return sign + "0" + value;
       } else {
          return sign + value;
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Time time1 = new Time(1,1,1);
       Time time2 = new Time(2,2,2);
       time1.add(time2);
       System.out.println("The result of (1,1,1).add(2,2,2) is " +
                           time1 + " and should be (03:03:03)");

       time1 = new Time(0,0,59);
       time2 = new Time(0,0,1);
       time1.add(time2);
       System.out.println("The result of (0,0,59).add(0,0,1) is " +
                           time1 + " and should be (00:01:00)");

       time1 = new Time(0,59,0);
       time2 = new Time(0,0,1);
       time1.add(time2);
       System.out.println("The result of (0,59,0).add(0,0,1) is " +
                           time1 + " and should be (00:59:01)");

       time1 = new Time(0,59,59);
       time2 = new Time(0,0,1);
       time1.add(time2);
       System.out.println("The result of (0,59,59).add(0,0,1) is " +
                           time1 + " and should be (01:00:00)");

       time1 = new Time(23,0,0);
       time2 = new Time(1,0,0);
       time1.add(time2);
       System.out.println("The result of (23,0,0).add(1,0,0) is " +
                           time1 + " and should be (00:00:00)");

       time1 = new Time(23,59,59);
       time2 = new Time(23,59,59);
       time1.add(time2);
       System.out.println("The result of (23,59,59).add(23,59,59) is " +
                           time1 + " and should be (23:59:58)");
   }
}
```

Comment: I didn’t get that, sorry. The line quoted in the error message is not in the code that you have posted. Then it’s very hard to help. Please post the code that exhibits the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add up the corresponding parts of time:

```java
public void add(Time offset)
{
    this.seconds = this.seconds + offset.seconds;
    if(this.seconds >= 60) {
        this.seconds -= 60;
        this.minutes += 1;
    }
    this.minutes += offset.minutes;
    if(this.minutes >= 60) {
        this.minutes -= 60;
        this.hours += 1;
    }
    this.hours += offset.hours;
    if(this.hours >= 24)
        this.hours -= 24;
}
```

Comment: You probably should not subtract 24 from the hours. In real life a time can be longer than a day.

Comment: I agree, and I didn't do that at first but if you look at his 5th "test", his expected output for (23,0,0) + (1,0,0) is (00:00:00) so I added that line